# Undefined control sequence when trying to use \newfontfamily

Tags: fonts, fontspec

File structure is:

```
fonts
     Roboto-Regular.ttf
main.tex
```

The document is essentially:

```
\documentclass{article}

\RequirePackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\RequirePackage{fontspec}

\newfontfamily [ Path = /fonts/,
 UprightFont = *-regular,
 BoldFont = *-bold, ...]
 {Roboto}

\title{TITLE}
\author{MY NAME}
\date{February 2018}

\begin{document}

\maketitle
\section{Introduction}

\end{document}
```

It then gives me Undefined control sequence, missing \begin{document}. I've tried so many things I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

EDIT I also tried:

```
    \setmainfont{Roboto}[
    Path = /fonts/,
    Extension = .ttf,
    UprightFont = *-Regular,
    BoldFont = *-Bold,
    ItalicFont = *-Italic,
    ...
]
```

Comment: You are missing the first mandatory argument to the `\newfontfamily` command. The first argument must be a control sequence, for example: `\newfontfamily{\myfamily}[options]{FontName}`

Comment: tried that but it's still giving me the same error when I add {\myfamily}, is that supposed to be a placeholder?

Comment: It should also be `Path=./fonts/`. Probably you want `\setmainfont` rather than `\newfontfamily`.

Comment: no I tried ./fonts/ as well, still same error, and I tried setmainfont

Comment: The *same* error? Probably not. With the same setup as you, I compiled with XeLaTeX and `\setmainfont{Roboto}[Path=./fonts/,Extension = .ttf,UprightFont = *-Regular,BoldFont = *-Bold,ItalicFont = *-Italic]` and it worked. Make sure you are adding the dot before the path and that you remove the `...`. Also check if the folder name has some capital letter. Off-topic: remove the `inputenc` package. You don't need it with XeLaTeX.

Comment: yea I'm getting the same error, I must be doing something deeply wrong. I am using sharelatex for my code not sure if that makes a difference.

Comment: Did you change the settings so it uses XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX to compile rather than pdfLaTeX? On ShareLaTeX, your path cannot possibly be correct.

Comment: also you are using `inputenc` (which should never be used with xelatex or lualatex) together with `fontspec` (which can only be used with xelatex and lualatex). So you should remove inputenc

Comment: do not post a fragment that is "essentially" your document post a _complete_ (small) document and post the _exact_ error message copied from the log file that you get from the posted document, otherwise it is very hard to help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others have already pointed out in the comments, your usage of `\newfontfamily` is incorrect. Instead of

```
\newfontfamily{Roboto}
```

it has to be like

```
\newfontfamily\Roboto{Roboto}
```

In the body of the document, you'd then write `... {\Roboto some text} ...`.

An MWE (minimum working example), which uses `\setmainfont`, `\setsansfont`, and three `\newfontfamily` statements (note that it's not always necessary to specify the `ItalicFont`, `BoldFont`, and `BoldItalicFont` options):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\RequirePackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont{Minion Pro}
\setsansfont{Myriad Pro}

\newfontfamily\Roboto{Roboto}
\newfontfamily\RobotoCond{Roboto Condensed}
\newfontfamily\RobotoMed{Roboto Medium}%
        [ItalicFont     = "Roboto Medium Italic",
         BoldFont       = "Roboto Black",
         BoldItalicFont = "Roboto Black Italic"]

\newcommand\hello{Hello World.}
\newcommand\blurb{\hello{} \textbf{\hello} \textit{\hello} \textbf{\textit{\hello}}}

\begin{document}

\blurb

{\sffamily \blurb}

\medskip
{\Roboto \blurb}

{\RobotoMed \blurb}

{\RobotoCond \blurb}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Just for future reference: the new font family name does not have to be anything like the actual font name. `\newfontfamily\beer{Roboto}` works just as well, and would be invoked as `{\beer This text is in Roboto font.}`

Comment: @RobtAll - In my answer, I was just applying what I understand to be established coding recommendations regarding how *not* to make one's code needlessly confusing, difficult to use, and prone to abuse. But, as you point out, if someone really prefers to name the macro that switches the font family to "Roboto" `\beer` (instead of `\Roboto`), there's absolutely nothing to stop them from doing so. I just hope I'll never have to debug their code -- `\beer` would probably be the least-problematic macro name that crops up...